# Update Series Array on HighChart after editing the chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, csv, highcharts

I am new to JavaScript and web development in general. I have an areaspline highchart and as part of a project, I have to be able to edit the chart by moving points on the curve up or down on the y-axis. I have created the chart from data in a csv file saved on a server. The idea is that I can edit points on the curve and then have that update the csvfile, which I can use later to create a separate graph.

I followed this example to implement the point dragging: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/AyUbx/ which is working.

The problem I am having is with the update of the csv file after I edit the chart. Ive been looking up solutions to the problem, but I can't seem to figure it out.
Here is the function in the jsfiddle example with the value I need to post back to the server and write to the csv file:

```
    drop: function() {
    $('#drop').html(
    'In <b>' + this.series.name + '</b>, <b>' +
    this.category + '</b> was set to <b>' + 
    Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2) + '</b>'
    );
    }`
```

How do I update the csv file on the server with the new value (this.y)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to post data to your server you can use the jquery post method :

```
drop: function() {
    $('#drop').html(
    'In <b>' + this.series.name + '</b>, <b>' +
    this.category + '</b> was set to <b>' + 
    Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2) + '</b>'
    );
    $.post("updateFile.php", { ypos: this.y , xpos: this.x} );  // like this
}`
```

**UPDATE:**

After, you just have to update your file in the updateFile.php page. You can access your data with PHP like this `$_POST['ypos']` or `$_POST['xpos']`

For example if you want to write the new positions in an CSV file :

```
<?php
// 1 : open the file
$myfile = fopen('myfile.csv', 'a+');

// 2 : write at the end of the file
fputs($myfile, $_POST['ypos'] . "; " . $_POST['xpos'] . "\n");

// 3 : when we have done, we close the file
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Comment: thanks! from there I just write a php script that updates the csv file? How do I specify which value in the csv file needs to be updated?

Comment: @bergundy195 you could pass the x-coordinate of the modified point in the POST request, then the server-side process can determine which point needs to be updated: `$.post("updateFile.php", { xpos: this.x, ypos: this.y } );`. Reference: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point

Comment: @bergundy195, if my answer satisfies you, would you accept it, or do you need more information?

Comment: Ya I tried it out there and it seems to be working. Thank you